# CentOS 5.5 needs xenblk.ko, what's the easy way?

Tags: linux, centos, xen

I'm taking a class on cloud computing and we're using CentOS 5.5 with xen. When I tried to run mkinitrd to build a vm, I got a message that xenblk was not found, and indeed I can't find the xenblk.ko or xennet.ko drivers. My instructor gave us the commands to build the vm, but I don't know how to install these drivers.

Quick and dirty, please. What's the best way to get a working version of this up and running? I'm running CentOS on VMWorkstation on Windows7 and it doesn't give me many options for install (it does an easy install, even advanced limits options quite a bit) but I can build another vm there's a kernel that has these drivers installed.

Sorry for such a homeworky question but these things are getting shoved in this direction by the StackExchange.

Comment: uname -r will show what ?

Comment: So you're using VMWorkstation to virtualize a CentOS box that will run XEN? You'd be much better dual-booting with CentOS then XEN can take full advantage of any hardware virutalization and the system resources. Have you tried a `yum whatprovides`?

Comment: @silviud uname -r shows 2.6.18-238.12.1.el5   @samarudge I agree, and so does my instructor (he gave me credit for the assignment because I've done so much research on the issue). But I only have an Ubuntu install on bare metal; CentOS was just for the class so I ran it in the box. It worked for everything else! (LAMP and what have you)

Answer (score 0):

Install the `kernel-xen` package. It provides `xenblk.ko`.

Comment: There's a post here that discusses the issue I think: http://zoetrope.speakermouth.com/2008/2/6/centos-5-kernel-2-6-18-53-1-6-el5xen-initrd-missing-xenblk-modules I installed kernel-xen but didn't get these drivers. The xen install was done after the CentOS install from the command line. I can't seem to find the drivers themselves and install them.

Comment: Its not pressing anymore: I got credit for the assignment, but I'm curious as to how to get the drivers and install them. There are a few people with this issue and the workarounds seem complicated, i.e. rebuilding the kernel. I'm new to CentOS, but for cryin' out loud, is it such a big deal to install a couple of drivers?